# Get the latest entries django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I currently have a function that writes one to four entries into a database every 12 hours. When certain conditions are met the function is called again to write another 1-4 entries based on the previous ones. Now since time isn't the only factor I have to check whether or not the conditions are met and because the entries are all in the same database I have to differentiate them based on their time posted into the database (DateTimeField is in the code)

How could I achieve this?  Is there a function built in in django that I just couldn't find? Or would I have to take a look at a rather complicated solution.

as a sketch I would say i'd expect something like this:

```
latest = []
allData = myManyToManyField.objects.get(externalId=2)
for data in allData:
    if data.Timestamp.checkIfLatest(): #checkIfLatest returns true/false
       latest.append(data)
```

or even better something like this (although I don't think that's implemented)

```
latest = myManyToManyField.objects.get.latest.filter(externalId=2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The django documentation is very very good, especially with regards to querysets and model layer functions. It's usually the first place you should look. It sounds like you want [.latest()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#latest), but it's hard to tell with your requirements regarding conditions.

```
latest_entry = m2mfield.objects.latest('mydatefield')
if latest_entry.somefield:
    # do something
```

Or perhaps you wanted:

```
latest_entry = m2mfield.objects.filter(somefield=True).latest('mydatefield')
```

You might also be interested in [order_by()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by), which will order the rows according to a field you specify. You could then iterate on all the m2m fields until you find the one that matches a condition.

But without more information on what these conditions are, it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot that was exactly what I was looking for. I feel pretty dumb now...

Answer (score 0):

IT's just a thought.. we can keep epoch time(current time of the entrie) field in database as a primary key and compare with the previous entiries and diffrentiate them